# Java WebDriverWait How to get duration

Tags: java, selenium, webdriverwait

I am currently translating a C# Selenium framework to Java.  In that framework I have a property that returns the current WebDriverWait;

`private WebDriverWait elementFindTimings;`
`.`
`.`
`.`
`public TimeSpan FindTimeout { get { return elementFindTimings.Timeout; } }`

I have translated this to a Java get method;

`private WebDriverWait elementFindTimings;`
`.`
`.`
`.`
`\\ The .getTimeout() method does not exist in the WebDriverWait class, I've`
`\\ put it in for example of what I'm trying to do.`
`public Duration getFindTimeout() { return elementFindTimings.getTimeout(); }`

However, the Java WebDriverWait - which extends FluentWait implementing Wait - does not appear to have a method that enables me to get the Duration value.  Obviously I'm missing something here as the WebDriver code that uses WebDriverWait needs to get the Duration.  Being new to Java I'm probably missing a key Java language thing here.  So, how do I get the WebDriverWait duration?

Comment: Just curious... what's the use case for wanting this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way.

Looking at the WebDriverWait and FluentWait classes the duration and internal durations are private and there are no public/protected methods that return them.

They do not need to be exposed as they are used internally within the WebDriverWait class - the function that is to be polled/waited on is passed in on the `.until` method.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't see exactly why would you need it, and as @Mat said, you can't really do that directly. However, as a workaround, whenever you set the timeout value on the WebDriverWait also store it on a separate field, and then read that field whenever you need to know the timeout value.
You can probably derive a class from WebDriverWait and keep this value in a new field inside that class, and provide a getter to it.

Comment: Primary reason is logging.  When the framework is in verbose logging mode I want to log the Find timeout and polling interval used in the specific Find instance.  The .NET `WebDriverWait` exposes the properties explicitly but the Java doesnt (using getters).  To get round this I just store the timeout/interval durations and instantiate `WebDriverWait` just-in-time when needed.